# Android null pointer exception while acessing the sms

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sms, broadcastreceiver

Getting nullpointer exception on running the doinbackground method.. This is my error![enter image description here][1]

this is my error :::

```
FAIAL EXCEPTION: AsyncIask #1

java.1ang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBa 45
ckground()

at android.os.AsyncIask$3.done(AsyncIask.java:278)

at java.uti1.concurrent.FutureIask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureIa 45
sk.java:273)

at java.uti1.concurrent.FutureIask.setException(FutureIask.java:12 45
4)

at java.uti1.concurrent.FutureIask$Sync.innerRun(FutureIask.java:3 45
07)

at java.uti1.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureIask.java:137)

at android.os.AsyncIask$Seria1Executor$1.run(AsyncIask.java:208)

at java.uti1.concurrent.ThreadPoo1Executor.runworker(IhreadPoo1Exe 45
cutor.java:1076)

at java.uti1.concurrent.IhreadPoo1Executor$Worker.run(IhreadPoo1Ex 45
ecutor.java:569)

at java.1ang.Ihread.run(Ihread.java:856)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

at com.examp1e.outgoingsms.OutgoingSmsListener$OutSmsLogger.doInBa 45
ckground(OutgoingSmsListener.java:45)

at com.examp1e.outgoingsms.OutgoingSmsListener$OutSmsLogger.doInBa 45
ckground(OutgoingSmsListener.java:1)

at android.os.AsyncIask$2.call(AsyncIask.java:264)

at java.uti1.concurrent.FutureIask$Sync.innerRun(FutureIask.java:3 45
05)

5 more
```

And this is my code..

```
public class OutgoingSmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

public Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new OutSmsLogger(context).execute();
}

public class OutSmsLogger extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final Uri SMS_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    private final String[] COLUMNS = new String[] {"date", "address", "body", "type"};
    private static final String CONDITIONS = "type = 2 AND date > ";
    private static final String ORDER = "date DESC";

    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private long timeLastChecked;
    private Cursor cursor;

    public OutSmsLogger(Context context) {
        this.prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("some_file_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        timeLastChecked = prefs.getLong("time_last_checked", -1L);
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

        // get all sent SMS records from the date last checked, in descending order
        cursor = cr.query(SMS_URI, COLUMNS, CONDITIONS + timeLastChecked, null, ORDER);

        // if there are any new sent messages after the last time we checked
        if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Set<String> sentSms = new HashSet<String>();
            timeLastChecked = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
            do {
                long date = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
                String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
                String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
                String thisSms = date + "," + address + "," + body;

                if (sentSms.contains(thisSms)) {
                    continue; // skip that thing
                }

                // else, add it to the set
                sentSms.add(thisSms);
                Log.d("Test", "date sent: " + date);
                Log.d("Test", "target number: " + address);
                Log.d("Test", "number of characters: " + body.length());
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putLong("time_last_checked", timeLastChecked);
        editor.commit();
        return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Did you add this permission? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>`

Comment: Yes.. Permissions are added.. @ShreyaS This is line 45: String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));

Comment: Do u get variables timeLastChecked  and date properly? Did u debug that?

Comment: Yes... I got it correctly..

Comment: Problem solved... Thank you for your valuable response..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it only showed up on some devices (or maybe I just always had some data before).

Problem is, that when you filter the result to the period where there is no data (for example you only want SMS for the last day and user didn't send any), you get **null** cursor. I find it strange and I believe on some devises you get properly initialized cursor, only it's empty, but on others you get null,so always check for null pointer before accessing cursor!

BTW "Problem solved" without providing the answer? Not cool dude!